# Enable RTS pin on Beaglebone Black UART1

Tags: uart, beagleboneblack, pins

I want to use `RTS` `pin` of `UART1` to communicate through `RS 485` protocol.

I have enabled `UART1` through

```
   /media/BEAGLEBONE/uEnv.txt
   optargs=quiet drm.debug=7 capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1
```

Device tree overlay snippet:

```
 0x180 0x20 /* uart1_rxd | MODE0 */

 0x184 0x20 /* uart1_txd | MODE0 */

 0x17c 0x00 /* uart1_rts | MODE0 */

 0x178 0x00 /* uart1_cts | MODE0 */            

 cat /proc/tty/driver/OMAP-SERIAL
```

serinfo:1.0 driver revision:

```
 0: uart:OMAP UART0 mmio:0x44E09000 irq:72 tx:2818 rx:100 RTS|CTS|DTR|DSR        
 1: uart:OMAP UART1 mmio:0x48022000 irq:73 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR|CD|RI
```

How to enable `RTS pin` on `P9.19` by selecting mode `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

The muxing mode of the pins both set to same mode. 
Change it to:

```
                0x180 0x20 /* UART1_RXD, INPUT | MODE0 */
                0x184 0x00 /* UART1_TXD, OUTPUT | MODE0 */
                0x17c 0x00 /*UART1_RTS*/
                0x178 0x20 /*UART1_CTS*/
```

To use the RTS pin send the pin number from the overlay.

```
                rts-gpio = <&gpio0 13 0>
```